# css issues display the horizontal line below Out of stock

Tags: css

please visit this link :

http://hotthjefj.com/x9460-disney-planes.html?___SID=U

here you can see  "out of stock" is separated by "Availability" through horizontal line.

but here it is fine

http://gfgfg.com/cbn10-disney-planes-avalanche.html

i want to display the Out of stock above that line

please help me to find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div with class `.Quick_2` has a fixed height of 115 pixels. Either remove that or change it to `min-height: 250px` to make sure it's high enough to allow for all elements

Comment: thanks @Sander Mangel for helping me on saturday also....

Answer (score 1):

you are giving .Quick_2 a height of height: 115px; comment the height out.
And you get the result you want